# wondering why the incorrect result is from the is_prime function

Tags: python

```
def is_prime(x):
    for i in range(2,x):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

print(is_prime(9))
```

this is my function to find the prime number, i am not sure why its always return True for 9, any helps and explanation? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why this is happening, take a look at what happens when `9` is passed into `is_prime`:

We enter the for loop, and set the initial value of `i` to be 2. Then, `9 % 2 = 1`, not 0, so the if condition fails, and we go to the `else` condition, which then immediately returns `True`: But this isn't the definition of primality. We need that 9 is not divisible by *any* number smaller than it (apart from 1), not that it's not divisible by a single number. So, we can only return `True` once we've checked *all* the numbers in the range, like this:

```py
def is_prime(x):
    for i in range(2,x):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Your code should now return the correct result for 9 (and, given infinite time, any natural number greater than 1).

A couple of things to think about: Do you need to check every number in `range(2, x)`? Perhaps you could look at what happens past the square root of `x`? Also, you might want to check if the number is less than 2 (i.e: 1, 0, -1, ...), because currently, your code will not give the correct result for these numbers. If you're interested also, the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a better algorithm than trial division for finding primes, which you might want to take a look at further down the line.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so can you be more specific about what the return True do which is outside the for loop? or it is just for checking all number and once all numbers are checked then the True will be return?

Comment: @MINO Yeah, your understanding is correct: Once the loop is finished, and every number has been checked, we return True. This is because if x was divisible by any of the numbers in the range, the function would return False, and execution of the function would stop. So, it's only if every number in the range fails to divide x that the loop finishes, and we return True.

Answer (score -1):

Because `9%2` is 1, and that is `True`

Here is how I fixed your code

```
def is_prime(x):
  for i in range(2,x):
      if (x % i) == 0:
          return False
print(is_prime(9))
```

HOWEVER, this doesn't take into account of 0 and 1. So here is a more correct one

```
def is_prime(x):
  if(x==0 or x==1):
    return False
  for i in range(2,x-1):
      if (x % i) == 0:
          return False
  else:
      return True
print(is_prime(9))
```

Comment: Your first code snippet is a bit wrong unfortunately: While it works for non-prime numbers, `is_prime(7)` will return `None`, not `True`.

Comment: Yup, that is why I added the second code ;)
The first one was mostly about showing him why the 9 didn't work, then the second code works

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense to clarify that in your answer then? Because the implication currently is that the first code should work for all numbers except 0 and 1, which isn't true.